# Trying to verify an index number from another method

Tags: java, swing, inheritance, awt, bluej

The first two methods are chunks out of my GUI programme.  There are various text fields that allow me input data and then buttons on the GUI take this data and call different methods.

```
public String getTenant()
{
    String theTenant = (tenantsNameText.getText());
    return theTenant;



public int getPropertyNumber()
{
    int propertyNumber = -1;
    try{
        propertyNumber = Integer.parseInt(propertyNumberText.getText());
        if (properties.size() == 0){
            propertyNumber = -1;
        }
        if (propertyNumber < 0 && propertyNumber >= properties.size()){
            propertyNumber = -1;
        }
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException exception){
    }
    return propertyNumber;
}
```

In this method I to take the data from the text field of "getTenant" and the data from the text field of "getPropertyNumber".  What I'm not sure how to do is check if the property number is -1 or not, and this needs to be verified in the method "addTenant".

```
public void addTenant()
{

}
```

Comment: You can just call the two methods in addTenant and use the result to do some processing.

Answer (score 0):

I possibly didn't ask the question right, but i figured it out with some help from a colleague.

```
public void addTenant()
{
    int index = getPropertyNumber();
    String newTenant = getTenant();
        if(index != -1){
            Property property = properties.get(index);
        if(property instanceof PropertyToLet){
            PropertyToLet propertyToLet = (PropertyToLet) property;
            propertyToLet.addTenant(newTenant);
        }
    }
}
```